# complex equation with non-zero $z^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$
(2+i)z^2+(1-7i)z-5 = 0
$$
I started with dividing with $(2+i)$ and got $z^2-z(1-3i)-(2-i)$. Now I'm trying to completing the square but fails. I get
$$
\left(z-\frac{1+3i}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{-1+3i}{2}\right)^2-2+i = 0
$$

Comment: You can use the quadratic equation..

Comment: @CameronWilliams: this method is equivalent to using the equation.

Comment: Completing the square hasn't failed, you just need to simplify the complex constant, take square roots correctly, and add on $(1+3i)/2$ to the result...

Comment: You have a sign error in your equation. I think you want $(1+3i)$ consistently - at the moment you have $(1-3i)$, $(1+3i)$ and $(-1+3i)$ in three different places - they should all be the same.

Comment: @MarkBennet Definitely true. I just personally would prefer doing the quadratic equation for complex quadratics as opposed to completing the square.

Answer (score 0):

Use the quadratic formula, and compute the square root of the resulting discriminant either by inspection or letting $\sqrt{\Delta}=a+bi$ and then solving for $a$ and $b$ by squaring both sides and equating real/imaginary components.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without the quadratic formula since I'm not familair with it yet.

Comment: You could attempt to complete the square, but that can get a little tricky if you're rusty with your algebra. Also, I find it very surprising that you're solving complex polynomials without knowing how to use the quadratic formula!